# How do I update the configuration of a deployed ARM template during run time?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have a logic app ARM template that is already deployed and at the time of deployment it pulls certain passwords/secrets from Azure key vault storage. But, what if someone changes the password or secret that is being used by the ARM template? 
One option is to re-deploy the ARM template. But is there an option so that I don't have to redeploy an ARM template and the configuration gets updated in such cases automatically?

Comment: If your ARM deploys the Azure key vault alongside the logic app. And during deployment you assign this passwords, then just make sure that whoever is updating those passwords is doing it trough the ARM template, in this case you would not have to worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so unless the resource itself is configured to pull values from the Key Vault - your only options is to rerun the template or update those values somehow, because this is what the template does, pulls values and applies them.

You can (perhaps) use something like Azure Event Grid to listen to events like KV secret value change. But I dont know if that listener actually exist.

Comment: I explored the event grid functionality and it seems promising idea. Thanks a lot!